# Custom toolbar on top of keyboard in landscape mode

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, landscape

I have a custom toolbar that sits on top of my keyboard that allows the user to select options for an EditText view. This works fine in portrait mode but I need it to work in landscape mode. As of now, my AndroidManifest for the activity is

```
    <activity
        android:name="MyActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
```

Here is the XML layout

```
<RelativeLayout     
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- some content, including an edit text -->

<!-- my toolbar that is supposed to sit on top of the keyboard -->
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/custom_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

As mentioned above, this works in portrait, but when I switch orientation to landscape, I only see the usual keyboard, and my custom toolbar is not there

Custom toolbar is supposed to be on top of the keyboard, but it isn't.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set `android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"` for `EditText` to prevent switching to fullscreen input mode.